# Vertical CSS menu clashing with overflow:hidden?

Tags: css, xhtml, overflow, hidden

Having some problems with a site I'm developing for a friend. I've been using a premade CSS-only vertical menu.

This have been working fine until I recently added height-scalable divs, http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/equal-height-columns-2-column.htm.

The menu still works, but somehow it expands beneath the content divs. I'm guessing this has something to do with the overflow value, but I haven't been able to find any solution. Worth to mention is that the menu works fine in IE8, but not in Firefox or Safari. Since the CSS is somewhat extensive I'm adding links rather then sample code - hope that's okay.

Thanks in advance! :)

The site is at http://dev.velkos.no/exigo, the CSS for the site and the menu can be found by adding /CSS (due to my newbie status here at Stackoverflow I can't post any more links).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Attempt #2 :)

Tested in Firefox, Chrome, IE8.

- Remove my previous attempt. On `.container2`, remove: `position: relative` / `z-index: -1`.
- On `#menuh-container`, add: `position: relative` and `z-index: 501` (one more than the `z-index` value on `#menuh ul ul`).

That fixes Firefox/Chrome, but breaks IE.

Now to fix IE..

The only way I could find to do this was to remove the `filter` rule from `#menuh-container`. Literally, removing the `filter` fixes it, adding it back in breaks it.

I'm hoping that your site still looks acceptable to you in IE8 without the `filter` rule.

---

It looks like this in IE7:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, again! :) This solution solves it in FF, but breaks it in IE. However, this isn't really a problem since I was expecting to have to make a IE-only stylesheet sooner or later anyway.

Comment: @KG Christensen: FYI, your site looks a bit broken in IE7 at the moment.

Comment: Darn it. Don't have access to IE7 now, so I can't really see it for myself. Hoping a IE stylesheet can fix it. Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: I added an IE7 screenshot. Could you do me a favour and *remove* the upvote on this answer? I'm very close to getting the gold badge which requires zero score accepted answers :D

Comment: Thanks a lot, should be an easy fix. Vote removed, you deserve that gold badge :)

Answer (score 1):

<strike>Adding `position: relative` and `z-index: -1` to `.container2` fixes it in Firefox/Chrome, and it doesn't change anything in IE8.</strike>

Doesn't work properly - see comments.

Comment: Whoops, seems I celebrated a bit to soon. Now all text, and thus links, are unclickable. I'm guessing this is due to the z-index?

Comment: Oops, you're right. I didn't think about that. I don't have time right now to take a closer look. I'll look again in a few hours if it hasn't been solved by then.